# Associate File in Parse.Cloud

Tags: parse-platform

I am uploading an image through REST API and getting an answer as below

```
{
  "url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/346a0978-68c7-4d08-a446-62f7422469e7/tfss-8b131ff0-5fd0-4dce-92e8-b7b94da5db9e-pic.jpg",
  "name": "tfss-8b131ff0-5fd0-4dce-92e8-b7b94da5db9e-pic.jpg"
}
```

I want to associate this image to a `Promotion` object. I also have a `Location` object which has an array of `Promotion`s. Here is my code:

```
function promiseToAddPromotionToLocation (locationID, promotion) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Location");
  return query.get(locationID).then(function (location) {
    var promotionObject = promotionObjectFromJSON(promotion);
    location.add("promotions", promotionObject);
    return location.save();
  }, function (error) {
    return Parse.Promise.error(error);
  });
}

function promotionObjectFromJSON (promotion) {
  var Promotion = Parse.Object.extend("Promotion");
  var promotionObject = new Promotion();

  if ("message" in promotion) {
    promotionObject.set("message", promotion.message);
  }

  //This causes an error: Uncaught Tried to save an object containing an unsaved file.
  if ("photo") {
    promotionObject.set("photo", promotion.photo);
  }

  return promotionObject;
}
```

When I comment out the part of setting photo, it saves the `promotion` properly, but when I try to set the file, it gives an error saying `Uncaught Tried to save an object containing an unsaved file.` How can I solve this problem?

By the way `promiseToAddPromotionToLocation` is called with the parameters below:

```
{
  "locationID": "fvOiAsoogc", 
  "promotion":{
    "message":"Some text", 
    "photo":{"name": "tfss-8b131ff0-5fd0-4dce-92e8-b7b94da5db9e-pic.jpg", "__type": "File"} 
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you're uploading the file using REST and then want to attach it to a Parse.Object using the JavaScript API?

Comment: Yep, uploading the file using REST and then want to attach it to a Parse.Object by using a cloud function which is called by REST. This cloud function calls the 'promiseToAddPromotionToLocation'.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this, unless you manually configure the internals of a `Parse.File` with the information (name, and possibly url too) returned by the REST upload. There's no documented way to do this, so it would be unsupported.

Comment: But isn't it like https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-associating ? So I upload the file. Then I call my cloud function with the file name from upload.

Comment: Ah, it turns out that it is documented wrong. I also need to give the url. https://www.parse.com/questions/image-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that I was passing the file info without url. [Associating file docs](https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-associating) show that it only needs `name` and `type`. However, this is wrong. It also needs the `url`. [This question in Parse forum](https://www.parse.com/questions/image-association) reveals it.